# RosActivity vs RosAppActivity

Tags: rosjava, android

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What is the different between RosActivity and RosAppActivity in android application?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/27765/rosactivity-vs-rosappactivity/) by [Alexandr Buyval](https://answers.ros.org/users/691/alexandr-buyval/) on ROS Answers with karma: 641 on 2012-02-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you're writing an Android application, you probably want your main activity to extend RosAppActivity. RosActivity contains the functionality for how intents are handled for starting activities. RosAppActivity extends RosActivity and it handles making the top bar on the screen with the dashboard.

---

Originally posted by [selliott](https://answers.ros.org/users/1745/selliott/) with karma: 51 on 2012-02-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1